# When trying to require a shared library (.dll) in Lua, I get the error "attempt to call global 'require'"

Tags: lua

I'm currently working with a system that uses Lua for scripting. I'd like to use C++ for some of the device peripheral logic that I have already, so I wrote a wrapper around said C++ logic so Lua could call it via a shared library. This works quite well in my own test script, which looks like the following:

```lua
myLib = require 'myLib'

myLib.callMyFunc()
```

However, when I try to the do the same thing in the system I'm working with, I get the following error:

`attempt to call global 'require' (a nil value)`

Why would this happen?

Comment: What system is it?

Comment: `require` might be deliberately removed for safety, as well as all other file access functions.  Do you have `dofile` on your system available?

Answer (score 1):

This question is not easy to answer because we don't see much code. It could be somewhere in the Lua code, the variable `require` being redefined to `nil`. But I don't think this is the root cause of the problem.

I believe the function [luaL_newstate](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_newstate) has been called without calling [luaL_openlibs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_openlibs) or similar functions. So, the standard library functions are not loaded in the interpreter.

I would suggest the OP to choose which [standard library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6) is necessary for his code:

> basic library (§6.1);
> coroutine library (§6.2);
> package library (§6.3);
> string manipulation (§6.4);
> basic UTF-8 support (§6.5);
> table manipulation (§6.6);
> mathematical functions (§6.7) (sin, log, etc.);
> input and output (§6.8);
> operating system facilities (§6.9);
> debug facilities (§6.10).

The function `require` belongs to the *package library*, so a call to `luaopen_package` is important:

```
lua_State *LuaState = luaL_newstate();

/* Open libraries */
luaopen_base(LuaState);
luaopen_package(LuaState);
```

---

For the sake of completeness, it could be interesting for future SO users to have the list of all the functions to copy/paste and adapt to their own project:

```
lua_State *LuaState = luaL_newstate();

/* Open libraries */
luaopen_base(LuaState);
luaopen_package(LuaState);
luaopen_coroutine(LuaState);
luaopen_string(LuaState);
luaopen_utf8(LuaState);
luaopen_table(LuaState);
luaopen_math(LuaState);
luaopen_os(LuaState);
```